# Padding with a calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to pad in a calculated field to get a final result length to be standard?

lets say I want my calculated field result to be 8 characters long beginning with MTX then enough zeros to pad and then the ID of the record.

So if the record ID is 23 then the result would be
MTX00023

Answer (score 5):

`=CONCATENATE("MTX",RIGHT(CONCATENATE("0000000",ID),5))`

Comment: It turns to `MTX00000` after item editing.

Comment: Well that's the joy of using ID in calculated columns, it's 0 after update, but the but for "supported" fields it's the way to pad.